# Allow single-line accessor (getter/setter) syntax with Checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle, accessor

We'd like to have trivial Java property accessors using a single line syntax, so they take up much much less space, and are more readable (in terms of 'seeing' the set of accessors quickly). But we do want to enforce multi-line method syntax for everything else in our checkstyle configuration. But I'm not sure how to make this exception for accessors in Checkstyle config and suspect it may not be possible.

So we'd like our accessors to look something like this:

```
public String getFoo() { return foo; }
public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }
```

[In fact we'd rather not have trivial accessors at all and instead just annotate the private member variables with `@Property` or something and have the accessors generated for us, since writing endless get and set code delivers no real benefit, but that's a general Java frustration and an aside as far as this question goes.]

Comment: I guess you have seen the Lombok project to answer to last paragraph...

Comment: or spring roo, for that matter

Comment: I would prefer solving this using the automatic code formatter. Then developers wouldn't have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this using Checkstyle, then you must write one or more custom checks. Your check would be a subclass of the check you are modifying. Then, for all checks that are affected, you would enter your own subclassed check into the checkstyle configuration (and remove the original one).

You might be able to cannibalize some code from the JavadocMethodCheck, which already detects trivial accessors. This sounds like a lot of work, but it's not much code because the modification you make in your subclass is always the same and can thus be put into a helper class.

I honestly don't think that Checkstyle can do it out of the box, sorry!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the [SuppressionCommentFilter](http://checkstyle.sf.net/config.html) to disable Checkstyle checks for a block of code.

It would then be possible to do the following to turn off Checkstyle like the following:

```
// CHECKSTYLE_OFF: ALL
public String getFoo() { return foo; }
public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }
// CHECKSTYLE_ON: ALL
```

Comment: The downside is that if some day one of the accessors turns non-trivial, checkstyle will continue to ignore it.